# Como alterar a versão do angular dentro de um projeto asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-core, angular-6

Tenho um projeto Asp.Net Core 2.0. Bem, preciso agora construir algumas telas para fazer um **CRUD** usando **Angular**. Deve-se usar o **Angular 6**, aqui na empresa. Bem, quando adicionei nessa **Solution** o projeto em **Angular** a versão desse **Angular** é a versão 4.2. Existe uma forma de passar essa versão para a versão 6? Como não é um **framework**, não é tão simples assim atualizar. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

**EDIT1**

Esse é meu package.json dentro da solution(Projeto asp.net core)

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
```

Se eu crio um projeto com `ng new [project-name]` e olho package.json, vai estar na versão 6.0.3, porem como eu estou criando pelo visual studio dentro de uma aplicação Asp.Net Core, aí é gerado o package acima.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui.
https://update.angular.io/

O angular disponibiliza o que precisa ser alterado.

Comment: @LucasBrogni, comecei a ler, mas veja. Eu falo do projeto que o Visual Studio cria dentro de uma solution Asp.Net Core 2.0. É esse projeto que eu quero alterar e não um projeto fora em angular em qualquer versão inferior à que eu quero atualizar. Vou ler, mas de cara achei não ser isso.

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse link: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/May/09/Updating-my-AlbumViewer-to-ASPNET-Core-21-and-Angular-60#ng-update